# Run query dynamically in stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Select all the tables of database where column match than pass table name to next query using loop. If column name and column values matches than return true and exist for loop using a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
(
NAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
ID IN NUMBER,
RE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS

BEGIN
OPEN  RE FOR SELECT A.TABLE_NAME FROM
user_tables A JOIN user_tab_columns C
ON C.TABLE_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = NAME;

FOR RE IN LOOP

v_Sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| LOOP.TABLE_NAME || 'WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 
ID';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_Sql
IF v_Sql%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
return true; 
EXIT

END LOOP;

END TEST;
```

For more understanding the problem

```
//Get all the tables of database where campus_id is exist in any table of 
 database
 Campus, Class, Section (3 tables found)
 Apply forloop on the records
 Select count(campus_id) as total from (table name using loop) where campus_id = 1(value 
 pass)
 if(total > 0){

 Exist for loop and return true
 }
 else{
 Again iterate the loop to next value
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described doesn't make much sense. If there are several tables that contain a column you're checking and you exit the loop as soon as you find the first one, what about the rest of them?

Here's what I'd do, see if it helps. I'll create a **function** (not a procedure) that returns a *table*. In order to do that, I'll create type(s) first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_record as object (tn varchar2(30), cnt number);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_table as table of t_record;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

The function:

- in a cursor `FOR` loop I'm selecting tables that contain that column
- `L_STR` is used to compose the `SELECT` statement
- `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is used to display it first, so that I could visually check whether it is correctly set or not.
- if it is, I'm running it with the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
- the result is stored into a table type and returned to the caller

---

```
SQL> create or replace function f_colname
  2    (par_column_name  in varchar2,
  3     par_column_value in varchar2
  4    )
  5    return t_table
  6  is
  7    retval t_table := t_table();
  8    l_str  varchar2(200);
  9    l_cnt  number;
 10  begin
 11    for cur_r in (select table_name
 12                  from user_tab_columns
 13                  where column_name = par_column_name
 14                 )
 15    loop
 16      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 17               ' where ' || par_column_name || ' = ' ||
 18               chr(39) || par_column_value || chr(39);
 19      -- Display l_str first, to make sure that it is OK:
 20      -- dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 21      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 22      retval.extend;
 23      retval(retval.count) := t_record(cur_r.table_name, l_cnt);
 24    end loop;
 25    return retval;
 26  end;
 27  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table (f_colname('DEPTNO', '10'));

TN                                    CNT
------------------------------ ----------
TEST_201812                             1
DEPT                                    1
EMP                                     3

SQL> select * from table (f_colname('ENAME', 'KING'));

TN                                    CNT
------------------------------ ----------
EMP                                     1
BONUS                                   1

SQL>
```

That won't work properly for some datatypes (such as `DATE`) and will have to be adjusted, if necessary.

---

**[EDIT: after you edited the question]**

OK then, that's even simpler. It should still be a function (that returns a Boolean, as you said that - in case that something's being found - you want to return `TRUE`). Code is pretty much similar to the previous function.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_colname
  2    (par_column_name  in varchar2,
  3     par_column_value in varchar2
  4    )
  5    return boolean
  6  is
  7    l_str  varchar2(200);
  8    l_cnt  number;
  9    retval boolean := false;
 10  begin
 11    for cur_r in (select table_name
 12                  from user_tab_columns
 13                  where column_name = par_column_name
 14                 )
 15    loop
 16      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 17               ' where ' || par_column_name || ' = ' ||
 18               chr(39) || par_column_value || chr(39);
 19      -- Display l_str first, to make sure that it is OK:
 20      -- dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 21      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 22      if l_cnt > 0 then
 23         retval := true;
 24         exit;
 25      end if;
 26    end loop;
 27    return retval;
 28  end;
 29  /

Function created.
```

Testing: as you can't return Boolean at SQL layer, you have to use an anonymous PL/SQL block, as follows:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_ret boolean;
  3  begin
  4    if f_colname('DEPTNO', '15') then
  5       dbms_output.put_line('It exists');
  6    else
  7       dbms_output.put_line('It does not exist');
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /
It does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort (Y). If you see your testing example. DEPTNO 10 count greater than zero in any row than exit the for loop and show result return true. I don't want to know how many time it present.

Comment: OK then, I added some more code (a new function) to my answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing how i return 1 or 0 intead of it exists or it does not exists using return statement.

Comment: Because i can call this function in store procedure need to return 1 or 0 than i would call store procedure from php

Comment: Instead of returning a Boolean, return NUMBER. RETVAL would also be a NUMBER, its default value 0 (zero). In line 23, set `retval := 1;`. The rest remains *as is*.